# Time difference in group

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have table as below:

```
    GroupOrderID    Station           Date
-----------------------------------------------
    28797   NB003   2013-01-03 12:53:00
    28797   NB003   2013-01-03 17:12:00
    28797   NB003   2013-01-04 14:45:00
    28797   NB003   2013-01-04 15:57:00
    28797   NB003   2013-01-06 16:08:00
    28797   NB003   2013-01-07 10:28:00
    28797   NB003   2013-01-07 10:29:00
    28797   CRM220  2013-01-07 16:31:00
    28797   CRM220  2013-01-07 17:04:00
    28797   CRM220  2013-01-07 17:04:00
    28797   CRM220  2013-01-07 17:04:00
    28797   CRM220  2013-01-07 17:04:00
    28797   CRM220  2013-01-07 17:24:00
    28797   CRM220  2013-01-07 17:24:00
    28797   STEENOVE    2013-01-11 11:03:00
```

I want time difference between two dates in seconds., for each station wise, Like Station NB003, CRM220 each have first and last date and I want difference in seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By applying the `max()` and `min()` aggregate functions and then using [`DateDiff()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) you should be able to get the result.

```
select GroupOrderID, 
  station,
  datediff(ss, MinDate, MaxDate) DiffSeconds
from
(
  select GroupOrderID, 
    station, 
    min(date) MinDate,
    Max(Date) MaxDate
  from yourtable
  group by GroupOrderID, Station
) src
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/044f5/4)

The result is:

```
| GROUPORDERID |  STATION | DIFFSECONDS |
-----------------------------------------
|        28797 |   CRM220 |        3180 |
|        28797 |    NB003 |      336960 |
|        28797 | STEENOVE |           0 |
```

You could take this query one more step if you wanted to know the difference for each date:

```
select GroupOrderID, 
  station,
  Date,
  datediff(ss, MinDate, MaxDate) DiffSeconds
from
(
  select GroupOrderID, 
    station,
    Cast(date as date) date,
    min(date) MinDate,
    Max(Date) MaxDate
  from yourtable
  group by GroupOrderID, Station, Cast(date as date)
) src
order by date
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/044f5/7)

The result is:

```
| GROUPORDERID |  STATION |       DATE | DIFFSECONDS |
------------------------------------------------------
|        28797 |    NB003 | 2013-01-03 |       15540 |
|        28797 |    NB003 | 2013-01-04 |        4320 |
|        28797 |    NB003 | 2013-01-06 |           0 |
|        28797 |   CRM220 | 2013-01-07 |        3180 |
|        28797 |    NB003 | 2013-01-07 |          60 |
|        28797 | STEENOVE | 2013-01-11 |           0 |
```

Comment: Can I write two cross apply for first and last date?  CROSS APPLY
(
 SELECT TOP 1 FirstMeasurementDate 
) FM
CROSS APPLY
(
 SELECT TOP 1 LastMeasurementDate
) LM

Comment: Happy to help. As far as using `CROSS APPLY` with `TOP` (see [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/044f5/11)) - The `TOP` will not get you the value for each `station`. If you don't care about the difference per station then yes you could use that.

Answer (score 0):

```
;with CTE(GroupOrderId, station, Date , r_asc, r_desc) as 
(
select GroupOrderId, station, Date , row_number() over(partition by GroupOrderId, station order by date ) as r_asc, row_number() over(partition by GroupOrderId, station order by date desc) as r_desc
from #temp
)
select a.GroupOrderId, a.station, datediff(SECOND, a.date, b.date)
from CTE a join CTE b on a.GroupOrderId = b.GroupOrderId and a.station = b.station and a.r_asc =1 and b.r_desc = 1
```